SaperaLT SDK Installer doesn't open on Windows 10 64-bit
I am trying to run SaperaLTSDKSetup.exe on a computer with 64-bit Windows 10. When I click on the exe file, I see that, the mouse pointer icon has turned into a blue spinning circle for a couple of seconds. Then, nothing happens. When I have tried that on another computer with 64-bit Windows 10, I could see a blue installation GUI is displayed. I am curious about the reason why this happened. I would appreciate if someone could help me with possible things to try out.
Kindest regards.
